# Multiple Pages within one Form? C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I haven't done this for a while so am not quite sure how to do what I need, but I am sure it is pretty simple.

Basically, I have a form with a navigation pane. I want to make it so when a user clicks a button on that pane, say 'Home' it changes the content on the form, but doesn't actually switch to another form, if you get me?

As in, I would like the navigation pane to stay as it is the entire time and I only want the content of the form to change. It is almost like the 'TabControl' tool in Visual Studio's 'Toolbox' although instead of the tabs being directly above the content, I want them to be buttons displayed in a side pane. See the image below for a better understanding. Thanks!

(Side pane, and header stays the same regardless on what button is pressed, but the content changes.)

[image: Form]

Comment: Did you try using `UserControl` ?

Comment: You can put your content into different containers, and hide/show them with your buttons. However, this looks like a big application, so from a performance / maintenance pov, I wouldn't recommend it.
An alternative is to put all your content into separate forms, and hide/show (and load/unload) them into that container.

Comment: Shame you are doing this in WinForms. WFP has much nicer features for this.

Comment: @Hyarantar to be honest I am not really sure how to use UserControl, I am going to do some research and see what I can do with it. The answer below about UserControls seems thorough so I will give that a go once I understand. 

Alexander I was thinking of doing that, but as you said, it isn't the best way in terms of performance. I go with that idea if I can't do it another way. Thanks.

MPatel yeah, I prefer WPF, although since this is for a University assignment I think they want us to use Windows Forms

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd implement this using `UserControl`s. One `UserControl` is shown when a button is clicked. I'd create an interface (for example `IView`) that would be implemented by each `UserControl` that declares common functionality, like for example a method to check whether you can switch from one to another (like a form's OnClosing event) like this:

```
public interface IView
{
    bool CanClose();
}

public UserControl View1: IView
{
    public bool CanClose()
    {
       ...
    }
}

public UserControl View2: IView
{
    public bool CanClose()
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Then, switching views is quite easy:

```
private bool CanCurrentViewClose()
{
    if (groupBox1.Controls.Count == 0)
        return true;

    IView v = groupBox1.Controls[0] as IView;
    return v.CanClose();
}

private void SwitchView(IView newView)
{
    if (groupBox1.Controls.Count > 0)
    {
        UserControl oldView = groupBox1.Controls[0] as UserControl;
        groupBox1.Controls.Remove(oldView);
        oldView.Dispose();
    }
    groupBox1.Controls.Add(newView);
    newView.Dock = Dock.Fill;
}
```

In a button you could do this:

```
private void btnHome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CanCurrentViewClose())
    {
        ViewHome v = new ViewHome();
        // Further initialization of v here

        SwitchView(v);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Current View can not close!");
    }
}
```

I've successfully used this approach on many occasions.

Comment: User Controls work brilliantly (so it seems at this stage), I never knew what they were lol.
Although, I have simplified your code a bit in my case. I only needed to implement the `SwitchView` method that you wrote, and instead of accepting an `IView` as the parameter I used `UserControl` instead. So in my button click methods I just declare a new `UserControl` then I pass that `UserControl` through the `SwitchView(UserControl)` method. Works like a charm.

Thank you!!

Comment: I've done it this way before, as well.

Answer (score 5):

Simplest way is to place multiple Panels as content holders, implement content manager which keeps references to Panels and with it show/hide desired panel.

Simple, but for smaller apps it will work

Comment: this is a comment/suggestion not an answer.

Comment: I wanted to add it as coment, however I dont have enough reputation. So how can I share that idea ?

Comment: that doesn't mean you'll earn repos by posting comments as answer,
try genuinely answering some questions and earn repos that way.

Comment: Manish: I dont wanned to earn anything, I used only way how to share idea. but thanks for feedback

Comment: @manish: What if he just enhanced this answer by providing more detail?

Comment: How do I implement content manager in order to reference each panel? I have never used Visual Studio or C# in this way, sorry.

Comment: i didn't mean to hurt you, so no hard feelings please. I was just making sure that answer should be useful. Anyways am Sorry, i have revoked my down vote. 
@ThorstenDittmar exactly that's what i expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a `TabControl` which has as many `TabPages` as you want. For the `TabControl` you can set the `Alignment` property to `Left`

Comment: Not exactly the look and feel that I am after. Thanks for the input though.