# C# .NET Substitutes for UserControl Panels

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm fairly new to GUI-development in `C# .NET`, using `WinForms`, and I'm creating an application with one form, (like a main menu), and with different "sub-menus", that can all be opened in the same form. This is what I currently have:

[image: Application with UserControl1 open]
*Application with UserPanel1 open.*

[image]
*Application without any UserPanel selected.*

I've seen some shady youtuber use `UserControls` for this, and that's what I'm currently working with. I'm using a `TableLayoutPanel`, with the `UserControls` dropped into it.

But I have some problems with this. First, I don't know if this is the correct way to use UserControls and if this will throw any errors.

Second of all, I don't know the exact way to use multiple UserControls in one form, because I can't drag multiple UserControls in a single cell of a `TableLayoutPanel`, and if I instantiate a new UserControl using some simple code, it won't display all of the custom controls I previously placed (in that UserControl). Here is that code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1_UserControl1 form1_UserControl1 = new Form1_UserControl1();
    form1_UserControl1.Show();
    form1_UserControl1.BringToFront();
    form1_UserControl1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
}
```

I know that this is probably a simple thing that I'm doing wrong, but I only need some simple advice.

Am I using the right control, or is there a better/easier way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: You don't need TLP, that can certainly simplify it.  Just a panel for the buttons, Dock = Left.  Display the user controls one at a time with Dock = Fill.  Be sure to Dispose() the previously selected one.

Comment: Your last bit of code suggests that you have called it a UserControl, when in fact it is a Form.  If it is indeed a Form, you can still display it in the Panel by setting its `TopMost` property to false before adding it with something like `panel1.Controls.Add(somethingHere)`.  Set the Dock property to Fill, and the FormBorderStyle to None to make it not look like a form.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322470/multiple-pages-withing-one-form-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

1. Initialize all `UserControls` to private fields
2. `TableLayoutPanel` add all these `UserControls`
3. Use buttons to hide/show them.

My sample code:

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private UserControl[] myUserControls = new UserControl[3];
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        InitializeUserControls();
    }

    private void InitializeUserControls()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < myUserControls.Length; ++i)
        {
            myUserControls[i] = new UserControl();
            myUserControls[i].Hide();
            myUserControls[i].BringToFront();
            myUserControls[i].BackColor = Color.Blue;
            myUserControls[i].Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(myUserControls[i]);
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myUserControls[0].Visible = !myUserControls[0].Visible;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myUserControls[1].Visible = !myUserControls[1].Visible;
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myUserControls[2].Visible = !myUserControls[2].Visible;
    }
}
```